# How do I change Time zone in android?

Tags: android, time, dialog, picker, zone

I have an edit text with time picker. When I clicked on the edit text getting time picker dialog. If I select 10:00 PM edit text should display 10:00 PM, but I m getting 22:00 PM. How can I change this? My coding part given below..

```
 protected void showTime() 
 {
    TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() 
    {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                        int minute)
                {
                    hour=hourOfDay;
                    min=minute;

                    if(hourOfDay>12)
                    {
                        hourOfDay -= 12;
                        zone = "PM";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        zone = "AM";
                    }
                    edtTime.setText(" "+pad(hour) + ":" + min+ " "+zone);
                }
            }, hour, min, true);
    tpd.setTitle("Select Time");
    tpd.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that you're only modifying `hourOfDay` as `hourOfDay -= 12;` Hence, you need to use the same variable in your `setText()` call as well because `hour` still refers to the original 24-hour format value.

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
        int minute)
{
    hour=hourOfDay;
    min=minute;

    if(hourOfDay>12)
    {
        hourOfDay -= 12;
        zone = "PM";
    }
    else
    {
        zone = "AM";
    }
    edtTime.setText(" "+pad(hourOfDay) + ":" + min+ " "+zone);
}
```

---

Please, use the Java DateTime API instead of employing mathematics to convert from the 24-hour format (that the `onTimeSet()` parameters come in) to the AM/PM one. The edge cases (like `00:00`) are harder to display otherwise. Here's how I would suggest you to do it.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a"); // [1-12]:[0-59] AM|PM

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);

edtTime.setText(df.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Check out the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) docs for more info.

Comment: There is a problem with 12:00 AM and PM. If I selected 12:00 AM shows 00:00 AM and If I selected 12:00 PM shows 12:00 AM? Why?